# Spring Boot log4j2.xml RollingFile Appender File is Always Empty

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I have seen similar questions but none of the solutions worked for me. My Spring Boot App log4j2 config is like this:

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration
xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t][%c{1}] %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">D:/dev/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console Appender -->
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="MyFileAppender"
            fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application.log"
            filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1000KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="FileLogger" additivity="false">
            <Level value="INFO" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFileAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**application.yaml:**

```
logging:
  config: src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
```

The logs are being written to console, also `application.log` file is created at `D:/dev/log` directory, but this file is always empty. I cannot find any solutions to this problem, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found the soultion.

First of all, I used to create **Logger** instance in my java classes like this:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);
```

But I had named the File logger as **FileLogger** in my configuration file.

```
<Logger name="FileLogger" additivity="false">
        <Level value="INFO" />
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFileAppender" />
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
</Logger>
```

So, either I had to do the following the following in my java classes:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FileLogger");
```

or, another way (which I preferred) is to add file appender to root logger. Here is the final version of my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration
    xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t][%c{1}]    
        %m%n
    </Property>
    <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">D:/dev/logs</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="MyFileAppender"
        fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application.log"
        filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100" />
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFileAppender" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```